# MySql query update doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PTC website where users can earn by clicking ads and referring people. The problem is on the referring people. Members are reporting they don't earn from their referrals EVEN if they click.

This is the query which is executed after a member watch an ands:

```
if ($user_info['ref1'] != 0 && $checkadcat == 1) {
                $refclass = new RefCron($user_info['ref1']);
                $ref = $refclass->get_info();

                if (($settings['clicks_necessary'] <= $refclass->yesterdayclicks() && $settings['click_yesterday'] == "yes") || $settings['click_yesterday'] != "yes") {
                    $ref_type = $db->fetchRow("SELECT id, ref_click FROM membership WHERE id=" . $ref['type']);
                    $refmoney = $ad_info['value'] * $ref_type['ref_click'] / 100;
                    $set = array("money" => $ref['money'] + $refmoney, "refearnings" => $ref['refearnings'] + $refmoney, "refclicks" => $ref['refclicks'] + 1, $refclicks[$refclass->get_chartnum()] => $ref[$refclicks[$refclass->get_chartnum()]] + 1);
                    $upd = $db->update("members", $set, "id = " . $ref['id']);
                    $upd = $db->query("UPDATE members SET for_refclicks=for_refclicks+1, for_refearned=for_refearned+" . $refmoney . ", for_reflastclick=" . TIMENOW . (" WHERE id=" . $user_info['id']));
                }

                unset($ref);
            }


            if ($user_info['rented'] != 0 && $checkadcat == 1) {
                $refclass = new RefCron($user_info['rented']);
                $ref = $refclass->get_info();

                if (($settings['clicks_necessary'] <= $refclass->yesterdayclicks() && $settings['click_yesterday'] == "yes") || $settings['click_yesterday'] != "yes") {
                    $ref_type = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM membership WHERE id=" . $ref['type']);
                    $refmoney = $ad_info['value'] * $ref_type['ref_click'] / 100;
                    $set = array("money" => $ref['money'] + $refmoney, "refearnings" => $ref['refearnings'] + $refmoney, "refclicks" => $ref['refclicks'] + 1, $rentedrefclicks[$refclass->get_chartnum()] => $ref[$rentedrefclicks[$refclass->get_chartnum()]] + 1);
```

Example: User A has been referred by user B, so user B should earn from user A each time he watch an ads, but this doesn't work. Even the db row doesn't update..

What's wrong?

Comment: Note: your code is (probably) heaven for a SQLi attacker.

Comment: `for_reflastclick=` needs to have `'` for the value

Comment: `TIMENOW` is a constant you've defined somewhere?

Comment: @Jeff yeah, it's a costant i use for store the date of the ad click.

Comment: Where do i have to place the ' in for_reflastclick=?

Comment: around the value (supposing it's a datetime string): `for_reflastclick='".TIMENOW."' ...`

Comment: Did you check for db-errors?

Comment: How to check for db errors?